# Regex replaceAll how to include the line seperator

Tags: java, regex

I use regex to remove all the lines start with a certian string, however it works to remove all the lines but the line separator still there, that left a lot of empty lines. How can I modify the regex?

```
public class Manipulator {

private static final String RECOVERY_1 = "RecoveryRate.1.*";

public static String remove(String input) {

    String remove = input;
    remove = remove.replaceAll(RECOVERY_1, "");
    return remove;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the `\R*` line break pattern at the end:

```
private static final String RECOVERY_1 = "RecoveryRate.1.*\\R*";
```

Or

```
private static final String RECOVERY_1 = "RecoveryRate.1.*[\r\n]*";
```

to match optional 0+ line breaks.

Note that you may tell the regex engine to only match these patterns at the start of a line with `Pattern.MULTILINE` flag (or its inline version, `(?i)`, at the start of the pattern , i.e. `"(?m)^RecoveryRate...."` will match `RecoveryRate` at the start of a *line*).

If the `.` before `1` is a literal dot, you need to escape it (`"\\."`).

Your method may be shortened to

```
public static String remove(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll(RECOVERY_1, "");
}
```

Comment: @QSY Oops, just noticed I left `remove` in the updated method, fixed.